# Verifying part of text in selenium webdriver

Tags: java, firefox, selenium-webdriver, automation

I am using Selenium Webdriver in my project and in 1 scenario I need to verify a String which is in the end.

**Text to verify** "This is a test event"

**Actual text which appears in browser** 
"When: Saturday, February 13, 2016 7:00 PM-8:00 PM. (UTC-06:00) Central Time (US & Canada)
Where: Drive labS

*~*~*~*~*~*~*~*~*~*

This event is a test event"

I am using following code to verify this

```
public static final By EventDescription_locator= By.xpath("//*[@id='divBdy']");
public String VerifyEventDescription()
{
WebElement eventDescription=websitedriver.findElement(EventDescription_locator);
return eventDescription.getText().trim();
}
```

I am calling the above function in my test script as below

```
 String description = "This event is a test event";
 Assert.assertEquals(calendar_obj.VerifyEventDescription(), description, "[FAIL] Event with description "+description+" found");
    Reporter.log("[PASS] Event with description "+description+" Not found <br/>");
```

Using assertEquals how can I just verify the specific text which I want.

Please suggest how to do this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Why can't you just use .contains() method ?

Comment: Where to use? I did not get you.

Comment: Assert.assertTrue(calendar_obj.VerifyEventDescription().contains( description), "[FAIL] Event with description "+description+" found");
    Reporter.log("[PASS] Event with description "+description+" Not found <br/>");

Answer (score 0):

There is contains() in Java.lang.String it will helps to check given char sequences in specified string and it returns results means true or false. for example

```
    String str="murali selenium";

    Assert.assertEquals(true, str.contains("selenium"),"custom message");

     //or

    Assert.assertTrue(str.contains("selenium"),"custom message");

    System.out.println("true");
```

Thank You,
Murali

Answer (score 0):

Please use  in the below format.

Assert.assertEquals("String Description","Event Description");

Just follow the basic  convention of Expected vs Actual.